# Entity framework 4 not binding properly to datagridview

Tags: c#, linq, data-binding, entity-framework-4, datagridview

Im running the following code :

```
    private void btnMatchFull_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Match m = Regex.Match(txtIP.Text, "(?<HostIP>[A-Z0-9.]{13}).(?<SubIP>[A-Z0-9.]{13})");
        string host = m.Groups["HostIP"].Value;
        string sub = m.Groups["SubIP"].Value;

        var abc = (from x in _db.HostIPs
                  where x.Value == host
                  from s in x.SubIPs
                  where s.Value == sub
                  select s.Nicks).ToList();

        dgvNicks.DataSource = abc;
    }
```

But instead of giving me the entity collection of nicks, each one with field of "Value" it gives this inside the datagrid view...

[image]

The tables definately have the data and I have used EF in a previous project fine and it did not behave like this.. so I have no idea why.

The edmx is like so :

[image]

**EDIT:**

I tried

```
var abc = (from x in _db.HostIPs
                      where x.Value == host
                      from s in x.SubIPs
                      where s.Value == sub
                      select s.Nicks).ToList();
```

And got the same result.

Comment: What happens if you ToList() and bind that to the DataGrid? Should tell if the problem is EF or elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a projection:

```
var abc = (from x in _db.HostIPs
           where x.Value == host
           from s in x.SubIPs
           where s.Value == sub
           from n in s.Nicks
           select n).ToList();
```